# Is hop harvesting before first frost necessary?

Tags: hops, harvest

Still relatively new to hop growing and this year is my first viable yield worth harvesting.  My cones are seemingly ready and some cool weather is on the way.  Do I need to get the cones off the vine before frost hits?  I've got one done and it is time consuming but frost may hit before the weekend, just wondering what impact frost might have.  Can only find frost related questions regarding planting.

Thanks

Apparently no tags have been created for harvest or frost, otherwise they'd be added.

Comment: harvest and frost tags added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, harvest them.  IME, frost burn will ruin them.

Comment: Really?  I thought people stored their hops in the freezer.  Or is it a repeated freeze/thaw cycle that does it?

Comment: When you store them in the freezer, they're dead, dried and vacuum sealed.  When they freeze on the bine, they turn brown and become pretty much worthless.